# IOS 6 Subclass not updating UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I have a UITableView it is in Prototype mode.  I have put 4 labels and 2 text fields into a cell, One of the cell is a basic text entry and works fine.

I have subsclassed the TableViewCell.

Header File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface witLeagueSeriesGameDetailCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *witGameNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *witGameScore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *witGameResult;

- (void) SetGameResult:(NSString *)resultName;

@end
```

Implementation File

```
#import "witLeagueSeriesGameDetailCell.h"
#import "witAppDelegate.h"

@implementation witLeagueSeriesGameDetailCell

@synthesize witGameNumber=_witGameNumber;
@synthesize witGameScore = _witGameScore;
@synthesize witGameResult = _witGameResult;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void) SetGameResult:(NSString *)resultName{

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",resultName]);
    //self.witGameResult.text = resultName;
    [_witGameResult setText:resultName];
}



@end
```

The tableview has also been subclassed.  It contains a picker that is popping up when the appropriate text field is being entered.  When a row is selected it passed the value back to the SetGameResult function, I can see this Using NSLog

However the text for the cell is not updated on the screen.

As can be seen by the code I have tried both the dot notion method and message method for setting the text.

The TVC picker code is

```
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    witLeagueSeriesGameDetailCell *myLabel = [[witLeagueSeriesGameDetailCell alloc] init];
    [myLabel SetGameResult:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.statusList objectAtIndex:row]]];

}
```

Any Ideas on why it may not be showing on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are IBOutlets so they ought to be connected to the ones on the storyboard.